# Android- Executing HTML request results in IOexception

Tags: java, android, http, ioexception

I am attempting to download the HTML of a given website from its URL.
The code to do this is in an Async task, separate from the UI, and the URL is passed to it, which is working fine.

The HttpClient is set up, and a request created, but when the request is executed, an IOexception is thrown. 
I don't understand why this is happening, as the URL is valid, and the app has network access.

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        Log.v("The URL is", url);
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.v("Progress", "Got to HttpClient");


            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.v("Progress", "Got to request");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Log.v("Progress", "Got to execute request");

            String html = "";
            Log.v("Progress", "Got to String html");
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            Log.v("Progress", "Got to InputStream");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                str.append(line);
                Log.v("The string is", str.toString());
            }
            in.close();
            html = str.toString();
            String TAG = "html extracted";
            Log.v(TAG, html);
        } catch (Exception IOexception) {
            Log.v("IOexception ", "IOexception thrown in RetrieveData.java");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Stack trace-

```
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=www.google.com
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:596)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:298)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at com.anapp.tpb.downloadhtml.RetrieveData.doInBackground(RetrieveData.java:43)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at com.anapp.tpb.downloadhtml.RetrieveData.doInBackground(RetrieveData.java:29)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-07 11:32:40.130    2168-2185/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: What URL are you calling and/or can you post the error (IOexception value)

Comment: post your exception log. in your catch block call **IOexception.printStatckTrace()** to get the exception log

Comment: Will do. I tried various common sites, which threw the exception, and then some more obscure ones, some of which outputted the HTML.

Comment: By default, try to use the second parameter of `Log` to print the exception, instead of a hardcoded String... The `Log` will say from where the exception was thrown... StackTraces are good :-)

Comment: Add `http://` to your url calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(from comment) When you want to call an URL, you have to start with:

`http://` or `https://`

For files (for comparison)

`file:///`

or

`ftp://`

in order to specify the protocol used

Comment: Yep, well that was easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I says,,, StackTraces :D... And it is easier to solve, if you (I in this case) have seen it before :-) (it never hearts to help)

Comment: While you're here, is there a way to check if the site uses http:// or https://? Or would I have to try it with each when an exception is thrown?

Comment: I can't say positively, but I'd say you have to try. Because `http` uses port `80`, `ftp` `21`, `https` `443`. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers nice selection of ports used (by default, *everything* is adjustable)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **schema** in the `URL` request, add `http` or `https`:

`path=www.google.com` must be `path=https://www.google.com`